# Why does it only add/minus 7 to the originally set data on mount

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

The two methods (addsevendays and minussevendays) are attached to buttons, I want them to plus or minus seven days on the date each time it's clicked but it only does it once either way i.e. 2019-09-10 will only ever plus to 2019-09-17 or minus to 2019-09-3.

Should it not do it from the new state?

```
data: () => ({
   today: null,
}),

  addSevenDays() {
    this.today = moment().add(7, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
    console.log(this.today)
  },      
  minusSevenDays() {
    this.today = moment().subtract(7, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    console.log(this.today)
  }

  mounted () {
    this.today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you always get the current time with `moment()` in your add Functions.

Replace `moment()` in your functions with `moment(this.today)`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    today: null,
  },
  methods: {
     addSevenDays() {
    this.today = moment(this.today).add(7, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    console.log(this.today);
  },      
  minusSevenDays() {
    this.today = moment(this.today).subtract(7, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    console.log(this.today);
  }
  },
   mounted () {
    this.today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

  <div id="app">
  <button @click="minusSevenDays">-</button>{{ today }}<button @click="addSevenDays">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: no! moment().format() returns a string! not a moment!

Comment: you should save the moment in a variable or create a moment from this.today each time

Comment: okay, then you it needs to be `this.today.format('YYYY-MM-DD').add(7, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD"))`

Comment: no, `this.today.format('YYYY-MM-DD')` is a string, you can't add days to it.

Comment: Im sorry Noam, did this solution as well as a snippet. We were working on the same approach I guess :D

Comment: It would probably be better to keep `today` as a Moment object, and move the `.format('YYYY-MM-DD')` into the template. That way, you don't have to keep converting it back and forth between a string and an object.

Comment: @TomMarienfeld that's alright, the main point of this site answers no reputation:)